# Access environment variable inside initializers Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, initializer

In my web application I want to access environment variables inside my initializers file.
My intiailizer file looks like(initializers/gcm_on_rails.rb)

```
configatron.gcm_on_rails.api_url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send'

#configatron.gcm_on_rails.api_key = 'abc'

configatron.gcm_on_rails.api_key == ENV['GCM_API_KEY']

Rails.logger.debug"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$  #{configatron.gcm_on_rails.api_key}"

configatron.gcm_on_rails.app_name = 'com.xyz'   

configatron.gcm_on_rails.delivery_format = 'json'
```

and In my .bashrc file I added following key value

```
export GCM_API_KEY="abc"
```

but my logger not giving me any value. that means I am not able to access those environment variables. I want to access those variables. Need Help... Thank you.....

Comment: You have used "==" in the 3rd line, are you assigning ENV['GCM_API_KEY'] to configatron.gcm_on_rails.api_key?

Comment: @Mohanraj thank you for replay. I want to set configatron.gcm_on_rails.api_key as a GCM_API_KEY which is set inside .bashrc file(i.e. environment variable.) any solution..

Comment: Hi, For your info. Rails loads the ENV from (~/.rvm/environments/) based on the version. I have checked when i add some variable to default env file under the above dir, it will be reflected on irb, but it is not loading in rails console.

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve set environment variables in your /etc/bashrc or /etc/profile, then these environment variables are made available in your shell. However, on most operating systems, Apache is not started from the shell and does not load environment variables defined in bashrc/profile, which is why setting environment variables in /etc/bashrc and /etc/profile usually has no effect on Apache (and by induction, on Passenger and Rails processes).

Ref:- http://blog.phusion.nl/2008/12/16/passing-environment-variables-to-ruby-from-phusion-passenger/

Comment: I tried your solution. I used 'GCM_API_KEY' but it gives me error "uninitialized constant GCM_API_KEY" I declared these variables in .bashrc file but still not able to access these values.. any other solutions...